# "Zend_Json Decoding failed: syntax error" when submitting order

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, error, php-7, json

I recently switched from Apache/PHP 5.5 to a new nginx/PHP 7.0.4 server and now I am getting once in a while a "Decoding failed: Syntax error" when customers try to checkout, apparently when they click the submit order button.

I am unable to reproduce the bug on my side, it happens in about 1 of 50 orders, sometimes also in the customer panel, so it seems to affect only logged users or SSL connections. As I am unable to reproduce the behaviour, I don't know what is happening on the frontend, but customers seem to be able to click the button again, because in most cases the order gets through after 2 error messages. The store is currently running Magento 1.9.2.1 and the server Centos7.

I know that the error is generated in Json.php in the function "decode".

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this and how to debug this? One way would be to log all JSONS with an error and then look at the syntax, but maybe someone already has a solution?

Here is an excerpt of the trace:

```
#0 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php(659): Zend_Json::decode('', 1)
#1 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Model/Session.php(133): Mage_Core_Helper_Data->jsonDecode(NULL)
#2 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(226): Mage_Persistent_Model_Session->_afterLoad()
#3 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Model/Session.php(154): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('deleted', 'key')
#4 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Helper/Session.php(67): Mage_Persistent_Model_Session->loadByCookieKey()
#5 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Helper/Session.php(91): Mage_Persistent_Helper_Session->getSession()
#6 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/Model/Observer.php(177): Mage_Persistent_Helper_Session->isPersistent()
#7 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357): Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer->emulateQuote(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer), 'emulateQuote', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#10 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#11 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(69): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
```

Comment: I am trying to hunt down the same bug right now: It is happening du to the fact that in Mage_Persistent_Model_Session  in _beforeSave() $this->getData() is empty so $info is empty and decoding fails.

Comment: @MichaelLeiss A user on stackoverflow pointed me into the right direction: PHP 7 throws an exception when trying to decode an empty string, this was not the case in PHP 5.X. A possible solution would be to pass "{}" instead of "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This has been resolved in Inchoo's Magento PHP 7 compatibility module: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Comment: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7/issues/29

Answer (score 2):

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php

```
return Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);
```

replace

```
if(!empty($encodedValue)){
    return Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);
} else {
    return Zend_Json::decode('{}', $objectDecodeType);
}
```

Comment: Worked for me thank you...!!! I was not able to save inventories config changes.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

> app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Data.php line number 657

replace

```
public function jsonDecode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType = Zend_Json::TYPE_ARRAY)
{
    return Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);
}
```

with

```
public function jsonDecode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType = Zend_Json::TYPE_ARRAY)
{
    if (empty($encodedValue) || $encodedValue == NULL ) {
        return Zend_Json::decode('{}', $objectDecodeType);
    } else {
        return Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the same issue while Persistent Shopping Cart enabled from admin. I fixed issue using above code